# Javascript write content into a PHP var to use in IF statement not working

Tags: php, javascript

this is the code:

```
    <script language="Javascript" src="http://gd.geobytes.com/gd?after=-1&variables=GeobytesCountry,GeobytesCity">
    </script>

    <?php
      $City = '<script language="Javascript">
        document.write(sGeobytesCity);
      </script>';

      if($City=='Tijuana'){echo'This is Tijuana';}

    ?>
```

I want to use the result from the `document.write()` inside a php var to validate the city, I'm sure I'm doing it right cause if I echo the `$City` var it prints the string perfectly well but it s not working when using the var inside the if statement.

Comment: You can't use JS (client side) to write the content of PHP var (server-side). Use either form-submit or AJAX.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-code-in-my-javascript-not-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP executes on the server and Javascript executes on the client. So you can pass values from PHP to Javascript, but not vice versa without AJAX or a POST or GET method.

Comment: Cookies can work as well. :)